# document.styleSheets does not detect all stylesheets

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to detect (and then change) stylesheet in any loaded page.

I try the folowing code:

```js
// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList
var allCSS = 
    [].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
        .reduce(function (prev, styleSheet) {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                return prev +
                    [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules)
                        .reduce(function (prev, cssRule) {
                            return prev + cssRule.cssText;
                        }, '');
            } else {
                return prev;
            }
        }, '');
console.log(allCSS);
```

When I run this code on this page for example, I get a few stylesheets in the console.

However this is *definitely not* all the styles, it is infact just a small portion of it.

For example in the debugger I see that the page loads `all.css` from 'cdn.sstatic.net' with many styles, none of them are shown.

What am I doing wrong ? and how can I get ALL stylesheets ?

Thx!

Comment: running your code in console in Firefox results in `SecurityError: The operation is insecure` - possibly a cross origin issue?

Comment: definitely a cross-origin issue.

Comment: works fine in chrome. Questions remain - how do I get ALL stylesheets loaded in a page ?

Comment: You can't, not without high privileges or without using a proxy. Now, you could test your luck, set the `crossOrigin` of the styleSheet's `ownerNode`, and reload it, but I doubt it will work anywhere.

Comment: as I said, it gives that error if you run the code directly in firefox console - which leads me to believe it's a cross-origin issue

Comment: When do you run the code? Can you reproduce the issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: I run it through the RunJS extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/runjs-run-javascript-on-p/aoibngbnkmhhbbjmlbaeffdhjgcnbggk?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [CssRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet#Notes)

In some browsers, if a stylesheet is loaded from a different domain,

 calling `cssRules` results in SecurityError.

- User agent (default) style sheets  aren't visible in `document.styleSheets`

## [The CSSStyleSheet Interface (specs)](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-cssstylesheet-interface)

The cssRules attribute must follow these steps:

- If the origin-clean flag is unset, throw a SecurityError exception.
- Return a read-only, live CSSRuleList object representing the CSS rules.

Comment: It's actually [now in specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-cssstylesheet-interface) that it should throw an Security Error

Answer (score 0):

If requirement is to get and change `.css` files loaded at `document`, you can request the files that you view at `DevTools`,  remove all existing style sheets from `document`, make adjustments to text of responses, append adjusted text as `.css` to `document` or at `<style>` elements.